# How can I print a word from an array?

Tags: python

Im trying to print the email of the student, in the while loop at the bottom im also trying to input the students email but I cannot figure how to do it correctly.

Code:

```
array1 = []

numstudents = int(input("How many students are in the class?: "))

for i in range (numstudents):
 studentname,studentemail,dayofbrith,monthofbrith,yearofbrith  = input("Enter the student name, the 
 student's email and the date of birth in the form 'name, email, day of birth, month of birth, year 
 of birth' :  ").split("")
 array1.append(studentname+studentemail+dayofbrith+monthofbrith+yearofbrith)
  if studentname == "stop":
    print("")
    break
  else:
   print("")

print(array1)


while True:
 email = input("From which student's email you want: ")
 if email any in array1[0]:
   print("")
   print(array1[1])
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you are making an array of strings; if you are going to be doing a lookup, it would make more sense to use a dictionary.  Is this a homework assignment where you must use an array of strings?  If not, perhaps clarify your question to ask how best to do what you ultimately are trying to do...  As a side note, I am not sure why you are doing a split, and then concatenating without delimiters?  That will make it difficult to pull out one item.

Answer (score 0):

```
students = []

numstudents = int(input('How many students are in the class?: '))

for _ in range(numstudents):
    print("Please enter the following: ")
    print("The student's name, The student's email, day of birth, month of birth, year of birth")
    students.append(input().split())


target = input("Which studen't email you want: ")
for i in students:
    if i[0] == target:
        print(f"The student's email is {i[1]}")
```

Try if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Ah, definitely a problem for a dictionary.

```
dict1= {}

numstudents = int(input("How many students are in the class?: "))

for _ in range (numstudents):  #As nk03 correctly points out - we don't need to carry the iterator, so can use an _ instead
    studentname,studentemail,dayofbirth,monthofbirth,yearofbirth  = input("Enter the student name, the student's email and the date of birth in the form 'name,email,day of birth,month of birth,year of birth' :  ").split(",")
    if studentname == "stop":    
        break
    else:
        dict1[studentname] = {'email':studentemail, 'dOB':dayofbirth, 'mOB':monthofbirth, 'yOB':yearofbirth}

    while True:
        name = input("From which student's email you want: ")
        if name in dict1:
            print(dict1[name]['email'])
        else:
            print(name + " not found in dict")
```

Comment: Huh - I didn't realise me adding in that comment would drop your edit note Nk03. Sorry!
[Comment probably good to explain to James why its done like that]